# TypeError: a.fn.popover is undefined in x-editable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I am using x-editable http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/. and i get an

> TypeError: a.fn.popover is undefined.

have any idea about this error?

Comment: Dude update the code which you have tried that helps to trouble shoot .Take reference at :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if you google the error you get this: http://blog.mattcrampton.com/post/65921067692/js-error-using-x-editable

Answer (score -1):

This basically mean that the variable `a.fn.popover` was not defined. This may occurs when the library (`jQuery` or `a` in your case) is not referenced in the calling script.